# How to run an process like ShowDialog()?

Tags: c#

I have two programms. "Programm1" & "Programm2". "Programm2" is run from "Рrogramm1". I run "Programm2" with this code:

```
Process.Run("D://Programms//calc.exe");
```

Is it possible to run "Рrogramm2" so that "Рrogramm1" can still be used but can not be closed while "Рrogramm2" works.

Can I do this with `Process.Run()`?

Comment: Which language are you using? Essentially, you want to wait on the process handle. How you do or access that, depends on the language and framework you're using.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2010 - C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell whether a process started using the `Process` class has exited by checking the [`YourProcess.HasExited`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.hasexited.aspx) property, possibly in the form's `Unloading` event.

If you want to block and wait for a process to exit, you can use the [`YourProcess.WaitForExit()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit.aspx) method.

You can find an example of this and more information in MS [KB305369](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305369).

Comment: Dianna, you missed never. I'm sorry, I bluffed. I didn't tell that I would like my "program1" to work. In other words "Program1" must be able to do its actions, but to be impossible to shut down.

Comment: I have two programms - "Programm1" and "Programm2". "Program1" has buttonswhich invoke different programs - "Programm2", "Program3", "Program4" . "Program2" is invoked by button from "Рrogramm1". "Program3" is invoked by button from "Рrogramm1". "Program4" is invoked by button from "Рrogramm1".

  I would be like "Program1" to do its actions - invoking other programs by buttons and "program1" can be closed by user if there is launched program. Ib ither words "program1" is like "menu" which invokes different programs and at the same time couldn't be closed if there is launched programs.

Comment: thanks, I understood that it is not possible. Thanks for your help.